# Different configuration for functional and integration tests in Grails

Tags: grails

Sometimes, you could need to split the configuration between integration and functional tests, Imagine you are using spring-security-core plugin and you don't want to enable it in integration test environment. If so, you could have something like this in your conf/Config.groovy:

```
test {  
    integration {
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = false
    }
    functional {
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = true
    }
}
```

So easy and so expressive.

Comment: No Tim, it was an attempt helping people with the same I had recently. Sorry for not being clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Grails config files are groovy files, meaning they are executable.  By capturing the test phase (unit/integration/functional) in `scripts/_Events.groovy`:

```
eventTestPhaseStart = { args ->
    System.properties['grails.test.phase'] = args
}
```

It can be used in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = 
  (System.properties['grails.test.phase'] != 'integration')
```

Here's [another example](http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/02/setting-grails-functional-test-database/) that does the same thing use a separate database for functional testing.